# database query for getting nid for checking duplicate title in Drupal 6.x

Tags: drupal-6

I would like to write SQL query for finding the node ID (nid) for which title matches a given title (value of title field value) for a give content type. I am trying the following-

```
function title_ajax_check_duplicate($title, $type) {

$results = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE title = '%s' AND type = '%s'", $title, $type);


  if (!empty($results)) {
    // This is a duplicate.
    return $results;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

I am not able to solve this for a long time. Any help would be much appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$results will return a mysql resource regardless of actual results I think.

Checkout [db_fetch_array](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_fetch_array/6) this will actually contain the results. You'd then have to iterate over the array of results to find the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Change you query line to:

`$result = db_result(db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE title = '%s' AND type = '%s'", $title, $type));`

Comment: Thanks for your response. My complete issue is mentioned at http://drupal.org/node/1051242. I am still fighting to make my module work.